# cant show a dialog gapi.drive.share.ShareClient

Tags: google-drive-api

Code lines:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, 
function (authResult) 
{
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
     gapi.load('drive-share', function () {

 var client = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(key);
    client.setItemIds([pathId]);
    client.showSettingsDialog();

     });
});
}
```

It always shows an error message instead of sharing dialog:

```
Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later
```

in message box.

Comment: Does your project include your page as a JavaScript origin on the API console?

Comment: I posted localhost:port to RedirectUris and JS origins. A call  to function gapi.client.drive.files.list(); works fine, and gapi.client.drive.files.trash works, but sharing is not

Comment: afaik "localhost" won't work. You'll need to create an alias in your /etc/hosts file for 127.0.0.1 and use that in the API console